# Using PHP MVC framework, selected value from db into select box is not getting populated

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, select, model-view-controller

My CONTROLLER is named Posts,

```
public function addmore(){
  
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
 
        $Asystemtype=$this->postModel->fetchDoctype();
                            
        $data = [         
        'Asystemtype' => $Asystemtype,
        'Adoctype' =>   trim($_POST['Adoctype']) ];
          
        $this->view('posts/addmore', $data);
          
}
```

My MODEL is named Post,

I have a database table named systemtitles,  with column named ID and titles.

```
public function fetchDoctype(){
      $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM systemtitles');
      $results = $this->db->resultSet();
      return $results;
    }
```

My VIEW is named addmore

```
<form action="<?php echo URLROOT; ?>/posts/addmore" method="post" >
<div>
  <label for="Asystemtype">System Type: <sup>*</sup></label>
            <select id="systype" name="Asystemtype" class="form-control form-control-lg" value="<?php echo $data['Adoctype']; ?>">
            <?php foreach($data['Asystemtype'] as $Asystemtype) :?>
            <option value = "<?php echo $Asystemtype->titles;  ?>"> <?php echo $Asystemtype->titles;  ?> </option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>            
            </select>
</div>
<div>
<label for="Adoctype">Document Type: <sup>*</sup></label>
            <select id="doctype" name="Adoctype" class="form-control form-control-lg" value="<?php echo $data['Adoctype']; ?>">
                
            <option value="Select">Select Doc Type</option>
            <option value="HRS">HRS </option>
            <option value="HDD">HDD </option>
            </select>
</div>
```

i tried to launch my website, These were the observations,
my SELECT box is simply blank nothing is getting populated, why?.
I printed var_dump from controller

```
var_dump($Asystemtype);
```

it was echoing all(that is in my database atleast i have five rows!).
Help needed for my select box to be populated from db for Asystemtype. My
Adoctype has no issues as I am populating directly from the form.

Comment: Try to dump $data in the VIEW and  insert the dump in your question.

Comment: Are you sure you should echo $Asystemtype->titles   and not  $Asystemtype['titles'] ?

Comment: I changed my code to this as suggested <?php foreach($data['Asystemtype'] as $Asystemtype) :?>
   <option value = "<?php echo $Asystemtype['titles'];  ?>"> <?php echo $Asystemtype['titles'];  ?> </option>
            <?php endforeach; ?> but still it is not having any data displayed. <?php var_dump($data['Adoctype']); ?> in my VIEW file it is displaying string '' (length=0) when I do a var_dump($Asystemtype); in my Posts CONTROLLER i am getting all my database(systemtitles) contents listed. i cannot understand why my view is showing null for var_dump.

Comment: Then the $data sent from the controller to the view is empty.  please dump the following values in the controller before this->view 
print_r($Asystemtype);
print_r($_POST['Adoctype']) ;

Comment: __ in my Posts CONTROLLER i am getting all my database(systemtitles) contents listed.__   Yes but probably you are using the wrong values to call the view.

Comment: sorry i did a var_dump($Asystemtype); actually in my VIEW only, but i typed wrongly. I also found that when I hit my submit button and posted the form in website, the var_dump($Asystemtype); from my VIEW, it listed all contents array (size=42)  ....but now in the form i have an error under the select box of system type as (!) Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClassas array in C:/wamp64/.../addmore.php

Comment: Ok then change it back twicew to  $Asystemtype->titles; Then the error should go away.  But still you did not post the dump  :-(

Comment: What you said was true!. I found my mistake. What I have done is  from my controller i was sending an empty data!! . In  my POST else{
   
 $Asystemtype=$this->postModel->fetchDoctype();
  
 $data=[
  'Asystemtype' =>'',
  'Adoctype' => ''] this was in my else statement of post. That is if I did not do a post then it was having 'Asystemtype' =>'' now i corrected to 'Asystemtype' => $Asystemtype,Thanx Alexander Dobernig

Comment: Happy to hear it is now fixed. :-) 
Please upvote my comments  and post the new code as an answer to the wuestion so other people can learn from it and add the tag codeigniter to each post if you use this framework. and also use it in the subject line

Answer (score 1):

I found my mistake. What I have done is from my controller I was sending an empty data!! In my POST else statement had

```
else{ $Asystemtype=$this->postModel->fetchDoctype(); $data=[ 'Asystemtype' =>'', 'Adoctype' => ''];
$this->view('posts/addmore', $data);
 }
```

that was a mistake. That is, if I did not do a post then it was having 'Asystemtype' =>'' as null value. Now I corrected to 'Asystemtype' => $Asystemtype
Thanks Alexander Dobernig for your valuable suggestions/comments